# Etymology of Thaligai and Samayal

Tags: vedas, vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, smarta

In Srivaishnava Sampradaya, the cooking of food is called "Thaligai" and in Smarta Sampradaya, it is called as "Samayal".

Can someone please tell me the etymology of the two words, Thaligai and Samayal?

When and How did they originate?